# FLV & F4V open source C++ decoder

Tags: c++, open-source, flv, video-encoding

I was wondering if anybody knows if there is some type of open source C++ decoder for FLV & F4V video files?
Basically what I need is to input FLV from a file system and to output PNG frame sequence back to the file system. I need the C++ code or the DLLs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use `ffmpeg` which is in C or simply run `mplayer` (check the command line args, it can output the picture sequence)

Comment: Looks interesting, but I need the code to be able to port it to iOS.

Comment: Thanks! I googled "ffmpeg ios" and it looks like there are already stuff that I can use.